# List of Applications which can handle intent-filter

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an application which can handle unique URI via **< intent-filter >**. This URI is Custom URI. For security reasons its required that no other application on mobile device can handle it via `<intent-filter>`

Now I want to find out how many **applications** ( not activities in an application)  on user's device which can handle that intent URI.ent-filter >**

Is it possible to do it ?
 If we can, then how can I get list of application names which can handle given URI in **< intent-filter >**

Answer (score 1):

An intent is defined at the Activity level, so you can't get a list of Applications directly, you can only get a list of Activities. You can then group those activities by package name and thus get the list of applications that have 1 or more activities that would be able to handle the intent. Something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(/* define you action */);
    final List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    final Set<String> packages = new HashSet<>();
    if (list != null) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : list) {
            packages.add(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        }
    }
```

The "packages" set will contain a list of package names, referencing applications that can handle the intent.